# Wrong price in url while using price filter - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, layered-navigation, filter, filtered-nav

I'm using Magento layered navigation. While I'm trying to filter by price it's getting wrong value in the URL. Like I'm trying to filter from $2.00 to $4.99 but the URL got 2-5. What I want is either the URL to get $4.99 or the price range show round price like $5.00 instead of $4.99. Please see below image for better understanding. Any idea how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Price range 2-5 in url work like 2 <= price <5 so it is equivalent of 2 <= price <=4.99 that displayed on the page

Comment: I was thinking how to elaborate this, but you actually did good and to the point. +1 :)

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's shows product up to 4.99 but i need to show that on the url. It's need to look like what customer selected.